# Interior and boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, but what are the boundary and interior of $\mathbb{Q}$? I think both are $\mathbb{R}$ because in any open ball centered at $q\in \mathbb{Q}$, there is any number next to $q$, there will be an irrational number.

Comment: The interior of any set is a subset of the set.

Answer (score 6):

The interior of $\Bbb{Q}$ is empty for it contains no open intervals. Note that the closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ is $\Bbb{R}$. Thus
$$
\partial \Bbb{Q}=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}-\Bbb{Q}^o=\Bbb{R}-\varnothing=\Bbb{R}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The interior of a (sub)set is the largest open set contained in that (sub)set. Thus the interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the empty set. On the other hand, we can approximate any element in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ by a sequence of rationals, so the boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.